# Axios accepts only static url

Tags: node.js, rest, express, axios, strapi

I'm writing a NodeJS Backend with express and axios where I fetch data from Strapi CMS and send a server-side-rendered HTML-document to the client.

There I encountered the strange behaviour that the first piece of code gets a response from strapi with data.data.length = 0, which isn't expected. The second piece of code returns data.data.length = 1, which is the same as I retrieve with Postman. I can't find the difference since both url's compile to the same string. My expectation is that both requests should be returning the same response.

```
app.get(`/blog/:URL_Identifier`, async (req, res) => {
  
  let data;
  let params =  req.params;
  console.log(params.URL_Identifier);

  let string = hostname + ":" + strapiport + `/api/blogposts?filters[URL_Identifier][$in][0]=${params.URL_Identifier}&populate=*`;

//string prints to https://127.0.0.1:1337/api/blogposts?filters[URL_Identifier][$in][0]=Blogpost1&populate=*

  data = await axios.get(string, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token 
    }
  });
  //data = JSON.parse(data.data);
  console.log(data);
  res.render('pages/post', {
    data: data
  })
})
```

Whereas the following code returns a data.data.length = 1 with the expected data inside.

```
  data = await axios.get("https://127.0.0.1:1337/api/blogposts?filters[URL_Identifier][$in][0]=Blogpost1&populate=*", {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token 
    }
  });
```

Is this a bug in Axios? I can't see the difference...

EDIT:
I tried the same with the http module from node and found out, thatthe request object from express might be the issue.

```
app.get(`/blog/:URL_Identifier`, async (req, res) => {
  let data;
  let doesWork = "http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/blogposts?filters[URL_Identifier][$in][0]=Blogpost1&populate=*";
  let doesNotWork = `http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/blogposts?filters[URL_Identifier][$in][0]=${req.params}&populate=*`;
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token 
    }
  };
  
  callback = function(response) {
    var str = ''
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      str += chunk;
    });
  
    response.on('end', function () {
      console.log(str);
      data = JSON.parse(str);
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
  
  var req1 = await http.request(doesNotWork, options, callback);
  req1.end();
```

This still gets me this as response

```
{
  data: [],
  meta: { pagination: { page: 1, pageSize: 25, pageCount: 0, total: 0 } }
}
```

Whereas  var req1 = await http.request(doesWork, options, callback);
gets me

```
{
  data: [ { id: 1, attributes: [Object] } ],
  meta: { pagination: { page: 1, pageSize: 25, pageCount: 1, total: 1 } }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `hostname` doesn't include the protocol. So they don't return the same thing. `console.log(string)` and show what you got

Comment: Hostname does include the protocol. I logged it and it was exactly the same string. I know that sounds weird, but I 100% sure